# Backbone: I am trying to fetch a collection (using a rails server). However, my fetch doesn't look to be working right

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, fetch

I am using a rails server that returns this JSON object when going to the '/todos' route.

```
[{"id":1,"description":"yo this is my todo","done":false,"user_id":null,"created_at":"2015-03-19T00:26:01.808Z","updated_at":"2015-03-19T00:26:01.808Z"},{"id":2,"description":"Shaurya is awesome","done":false,"user_id":null,"created_at":"2015-03-19T00:40:48.458Z","updated_at":"2015-03-19T00:40:48.458Z"},{"id":3,"description":"your car needs to be cleaned","done":false,"user_id":null,"created_at":"2015-03-19T00:41:08.527Z","updated_at":"2015-03-19T00:41:08.527Z"}]
```

I am using this code for my collection.

```
var app = app || {};
var TodoList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: app.Todo,
  url: '/todos'
});
app.Todos = new TodoList();
```

However, when trying to fetch the data it states that the object is undefined. I originally thought that my function wasn't parsing the JSON correctly. However, that doesn't look to be the case. I created a parse function with a debugger in it to look at the response. In gives back, an array with three objects.

Here what happens when I try testing the fetch().

```
var todos = app.Todos.fetch()
todos.length // returns undefined
todos.get(1) // TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

The todos collection doesn't automatically populate the function get() in console. I am running out of ideas of what can be the problem. Please help. Thanks!

Comment: Here is an image of the console and the object I get back. It also has the response when I threw in a debugger. http://i.stack.imgur.com/uGmxz.png

Comment: Ok I think I see what is happening. app.Todos will give me my JSON after my fetch, not app.Todos.fetch()

Answer (score 1):

Fetch is a ayncronous, you need to listen to the add event:

```
var todos = app.Todos.fetch()
todos.on('add', function(model){
  console.log(todos.length);
});
```

If you pass the parameter reset, you could listen for the would new models:

```
var todos = app.Todos.fetch({reset: true})
todos.on('reset', function(model){
  console.log(todos.length);
});
```

You could also read [here](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch).

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems:

1. [Fetch](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch) is asynchronous; we don't know exactly when we'll have a result, but we do know that it won't be there when you are calling todos.length.
2. Fetch sets the collection's contents when it receives a response; calling `app.Todos.fetch()` will result in `app.Todos` containing whatever models were fetched by the request. Its return value is not useful for inspecting the collection, so `var todos = app.Todos.fetch()` won't give you what you want in any case.

If you want to inspect what you receive from the server, your best option is to set a success callback:

```
app.Todos.fetch({
  success: function (collection, response, options) {
    console.log(collection);
  }
});
```